# getting internal server error 500, after adding multiple instances in backend pool of azure application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer

I have been trying to add multiple backend pools (multiple IP addresses) in the Azure Application Gateway, to route the request to any one of the servers mentioned.

once I have added two servers to the pool, the request is now showing a 500 internal server error. but it will work when only 1 instance is added to the backend pool.
The servers which I have added are 2 VM's IP address. In backend health also I could see the servers as healthy.
what could be the issue?

Comment: not sure how your actual arch,but 5XX mean there issue in application mainly internally either not able to handle request, failed connecting to db or so. now if you are adding 1 instance could be chance that instace is not able to connect with db and failing so you will get 5XX. while for other instace ip whitelisted or so and it's working. check both instaces ports open and app working inside it first.

Answer (score 0):

Go to backend settings and try enabling Cookie-based affinity

[image]